# JButton added, But Not Visible at runtime

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

```
public class Pencere{
    JFrame pencere = new JFrame();
    JButton buton1, buton2;

    public Pencere() {
        pencere.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pencere.setTitle("Ana Pencere");
        pencere.setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(15f, 120f, 220f));
        pencere.setLocation(new Point(500, 300));
        pencere.setSize(613, 253);
        pencere.addMouseListener(new Dinle());
        pencere.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        pencereDegis();
    }
    public void goster(){
        pencere.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void pencereDegis(){
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
                | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        buton2 = new JButton("Butonnn"); //This button not visible
        pencere.add(buton2);
        pencere.pack();
    }
}
```

When i run my app **(I show JFrame window)**, all code work normally but when invoke pencereDegis() method after i dont saw "Butonnn" button.

Sory for my bad english thank you all..

Comment: When is the goster() method called? Can we see your main method that launches the app?

Comment: public class AnaMetod {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Pencere pencere = new Pencere();
  pencere.goster();
 }
}

Comment: Just comment the `try-catch` block that you have written within `goster()` method for a while and then run the program.. Aside from this , never add components directly on `JFrame` instead retrieve the `Container` using `pencere.getContentPane()` and then add the components on that `Container`.

Comment: yes i write it in main method all work normally but i cant saw buton2 :/ i'm try this pencere.getContentPane().add(buton2); but not work

Comment: I tried it with this code and `pencere.goster()` in my `main()` and it works well. About your `LookAndFeel`, take care because this code won't run on every OS. You should do instead : `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());`

Comment: @VishalK There is no `try-catch` in the `goster` method, do you mean the `pencereDegis` method. I to ran the code without commenting anything out and it works just fine.

Comment: @Byron: My mistake ..I was talking about the `try-catch` block in `pencereDegis()` method.. instead.. There might be some issue with `look and feel` on OP system. It too working fine on my system..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works well for me with `goster()` call in the `main` method.
The button `buton2` is visible (I just uncommented your `addMouseListener()` as I don't have `Dinle` class).
I'm not sure with it but this may be because of your `LookAndFeel` statement. I have OSX and I couldn't display your frame at first time (because you were using `WindowsLookAndFeel`), but with this correction it works well.

```
public class Pencere{
    JFrame pencere = new JFrame();
    JButton buton1, buton2;

    public Pencere() {
        pencere.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pencere.setTitle("Ana Pencere");
        pencere.setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(15f, 120f, 220f));
        pencere.setLocation(new Point(500, 300));
        pencere.setSize(613, 253);
        //pencere.addMouseListener(new Dinle());
        pencere.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        pencereDegis();
    }
    public void goster(){
        pencere.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void pencereDegis(){
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
                | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        buton2 = new JButton("Butonnn"); //This button not visible
        pencere.add(buton2);
        pencere.pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Pencere p = new Pencere();
        p.goster();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] arg)
{
    pencereDegis();
    goster();
}
```

Include this into your code, it works.